# Create/Write INI file without needing admin privileges?

Tags: c, winapi, ini

When creating and/or writting to a INI file - do I always need elevated/admin privileges?

I have a simple app that arranges open windows so it doesn't make sense for it to need admin privileges. But AFAIK, I need admin privileges to create the INI registry entry `RegCreateKeyEx` then `WritePrivateProfileString`. The information I am storing in the INI file is not confidential - just HWND sizing and position information.

Is it possible to just have a public INI file stored in `%APPDATA%`? I can see that Thunderbird has its INI file in `%APPDATA%`. Is it possible to create and/or write to an INI file without needing admin/elevated privileges?

Comment: I think it depends your user level. If you are a simple user, you don't need admin privileges because you are storing in your user space.

Comment: You need the same permissions you would need to write any file into the folder in question, there's nothing special about INI files in this regard.

Comment: `RegCreateKeyEx` has nothing to do with INI files; I'm not sure why you've mentioned it. Can you clarify exactly what you're attempting to do, and include your code?

Comment: @KenWhite The https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx example uses `RegCreateKeyEx `

Comment: Ugh. That example is so poor it's shameful. But it explains the problem; the example writes to HKLM, and **that** requires elevated permissions. Omit the part about writing to that registry key, and just include the full path to your INI file in `lpFileName` along with the INI file name.

Comment: @Merl That example is for redirecting WritePrivateProfileString calls into the registry. This is typically needed only as an app compat mitigation. For a regular app, just call WritePrivateProfileString with a full path to your INI file.

Comment: @Merl: And yes, do store your INI file in a subfolder within `%APPDATA%` or other appropriate location: [Where Should I Store my Data and Configuration Files if I Target Multiple OS Versions?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions/)

Comment: *WritePrivateProfileString function
Copies a string into the specified section of an initialization file.
Note  This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit versions of Windows. Applications should store initialization information in the registry.* This function was deprecated years ago.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Without a viable replacement strategy, developers will continue to use this API, irrespective of whether it is deprecated. The proposed workaround/future-proof solution to use the registry doesn't address the specific feature, why developers still use this API (e.g. to enable portable applications, or xcopy deployment). Unless you can recommend a true replacement for the `WritePrivateProfileXxx` family of functions, there is little merit in suggesting to not use it.

Comment: @IInspectable There are many libraries for reading and writing .ini files, no point to use a horribly deprecated one full of compat shims that hurt

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Using (and deploying/maintaining) another library for something that can be done without a 3rd party library dependency is not a step in the right direction. The issues around the `WritePrivateProfileXxx` family of functions are well understood and documented. This may not be the case with a random 3rd party library.

Comment: @IInspectable I disagree entirely.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: This much has become apparent. However, neither you nor the MSDN offer a satisfactory replacement strategy. It's like *"I need to cross this street"* and your answer is: *"Don't. Crossing streets is so last millennium."* This isn't very helpful.

Comment: @iinspectable There are many libraries that provide ini file functionality. I'm sure you could find good ones if you looked. I would expect any programmer to be able to do so. Why should MS be in the business of recommending ini parsers?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: *"Why should MS be in the business of recommending ini parsers?"* - Right, they aren't. Because they already have one. There is absolutely nothing, zero, nada to be gained from taking to a 3rd party library. Or are you afraid, that suddenly Microsoft would break all drivers that ship with INF installers, before that 3rd party library stops being actively supported? Bottom line is: If you want developers to stop using something, you have to tell them why, and what to use instead. Neither you nor Microsoft have brought a viable alternative to the table.

Comment: @IInspectable The MS ini API is deprecated. It is slow, and it has weird and unpredictable compat shims. I doubt MS use it to parse INF files. Using something crappy because you aren't capable of looking around is rather pathetic.

Comment: @IInspectable: "The issues around the WritePrivateProfileXxx family of functions are well understood and documented." - Could you provide a link *where* these issues are documented? I'm currently [trying to figure out these issues](https://github.com/WelliSolutions/IniFileFormatReverseEngineering) and would be glad if there are some pointers.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Dear Raymond, I have a suggestion for "The old new thing". There seem to be weird limits on when text in a single line textbox becomes invisible. That value has been 5460, then 10919 and now 43679 characters. There are >10 questions about this on Stack Overflow, but nobody can give a definite answer. It's all wild guesses. See questions 10361855, 14355427, 25709069, 26250761, 39847121 and others

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. For `WritePrivateProfileString()`, provide a full file name including drive and directory to `lpFileName` and it will write there, given the user has enough permissions to write there.

You can write an INI file to `%AppData%` without special privileges:

```
var appData = Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData;
var lpFileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(appData);
lpFileName = Path.Combine(lpFileName, "x.ini");
WritePrivateProfileStringW("section", "key", "value", lpFileName);
Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(lpFileName));
```